# Copy images in subfolders to another using Python

Tags: python, image, copy

I have a folder with many subfolders that contains images. I want to copy these images of the subfolders to the destination folder. All images should be in one folder. With my current code, Python copies all subfolders to the destination folder, but thats not what I want. I only what the .jpg images. My current code is:

```
dir_src = r"/path/to/folder/with/subfolders"
dir_dst = r"/path/to/destination" 
for file in os.listdir(dir_src):
    print(file) 
    src_file = os.path.join(dir_src, file)
    dst_file = os.path.join(dir_dst, file)
    shutil.copytree(src_file, dst_file)
```

I'm grateful for every tip

Comment: filter by file, you may use `glob` for taking the jpg images only

Comment: Thanks for your fast respond! I edited the code with glob. Now I can find all images with this code. But how can I copy these to the destination folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `os.walk`:

```
import os
from shutil import copy
dir_src = r"/path/to/folder/with/subfolders"
dir_dst = r"/path/to/destination"
for root, _, files in os.walk(dir_src):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('.jpg'):
            copy(os.path.join(root, file), dir_dst)
```

or you can use `glob` if you're using Python 3.5+:

```
import glob
from shutil import copy
dir_src = r"/path/to/folder/with/subfolders"
dir_dst = r"/path/to/destination"
for file in glob.iglob('%s/**/*.jpg' % dir_src, recursive=True):
    copy(file, dir_dst)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This code was the solution for my problem!